# Problems trying to use Visual Studio 2010 and AJAX extensions

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010

Why can I not add ScriptManager control or UpdatePanel to a page in Visual Studio 2010?

The drag( or double click) just fails - it seems like there is an incompatibility somewhere?

UPDATE:
This is 'default' install of 2010 Ultimate on Windows7, create a web application, cannot drag ScriptManager or UpdatePanel to the designer. Typing the declarations works.

The cursor changes to the [+]  icon when you drag it to the right place but nothing appears to happens on 'drop', briefly the documents name has * appended, this quickly changes back to normal, either is saves or does an undo.

I'm assuming something is going wrong so it undos...but what is going wrong?

Comment: Typing it in still works fine; I've had no issues there, as an alternative.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I'm working with UpdatePanel and VS 2010 without a problem, so I guess it would be a local problem for you. Could you please give us more details about your exact scenario, fore example code snippet or other useful information. Thanks...

Comment: I've added a little more detail to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem easily by resetting your toolbox.

Mahmut.